# How to find words with all uppercase letters without space?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a bibliography file with a sample entry as shown below:

```
@article{le1993new,
  title={A new simplified acute physiology score (SAPS II) based on a European/North American multicenter study},
  author={Le Gall, Jean-Roger and Lemeshow, Stanley and Saulnier, Fabienne},
  journal={Jama},
  volume={270},
  number={24},
  pages={2957--2963},
  year={1993},
  publisher={American Medical Association}
}
```

I want to find all words with uppercase letters with regex in this case "SAPS" and "II". The following regular expression didn't find the required words:

```
(?=[A-Z])([A-Z\s]+)
```

How should the regex (for ST3) be for finding all uppercase letters without space?

Comment: Are you using *Find* feature? Then you need a PCRE regex. Try `\b\p{Lu}+\b` or `\b\p{Lu}{2,}\b` (or in Python, stick to ASCII only `\b[A-Z]{2,}\b`). What are the exact pattern criteria? 2 or more uppercase letters? Or do you want to get `SAPS II` as a single match?

Comment: What tag is relevant: SublimeText3 or Python? Show your code (or confirm you only want to work with SublimeText).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 2 or more uppercase. And not as a single match. It should work in ST3.

Comment: Just a matter of `\b[A-Z]{2,}\b`

Comment: @revo I already suggested `\b[A-Z]{2,}\b`. No feedback so far. Tom, please review the suggestions in my first comment and let know if any of them works as expected.

Comment: I suggest using the following, if you want every word, no matter the length, to be included: `\b[A-Z]+\b`. Note that this will also match single letters that are uppercase. If you want to specify a minimum length for your words, use: something like `\b[A-Z]{3,}\b`, which will match any all-uppercase word that has a length of at least 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `(?=[A-Z])([A-Z\s]+)` first makes sure there is an uppercase ASCII letter immediately to the right of the current location, and then matches (consumes) 1 or more chars that are either uppercase ASCII chars or whitespace chars. It will match `A` in `Alice` because `A` meets the lookahead restriction and matches a letter. As there is no word boundary at the end of the pattern, a valid match `A` is returned. It will also match `SAPS II` (with a trailing space) because the `\s` matches a whitespace, and `+` will greedily grab all the consecutive uppercase letters and whitespace.

A regex that will find all whole words consisting of 2 or more uppercase chars that will work in SublimeText3 is

```
\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[[:upper:]]{2,}` - 2 or more uppercase letters
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Comment: Note that in Sublime Text 3, the `[[:upper:]]` POSIX character class also matches Unicode uppercase letters.

Comment: It does work on Windows, but does not on Linux. I wonder why?

Comment: @TomKurushingal Are you running it under Wine?

Comment: No. ST3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without Wine.

Comment: @TomKurushingal I installed the ST3 build on Ubuntu 14, and it works the same. Did you check the regex and case sensitive mode? Press CTRL+R and CTRL+C or just check the first leftmost icons in the bottom left-hand corner of the application. I.e. `.*`  and `Aa` must be on (as on my screenshot in the answer).

Comment: It was the case sensitive mode that messed it up. I assumed regex would be independent of the case sensitive mode. It does work.

Comment: @TomKurushingal: If you wish to make the pattern work regardless of the `Aa` option state, you may use `(?-i)\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b`. The `(?-i)` before the pattern tells the app to apply the regex in the case-sensitive way.

Comment: `A regex that will find all whole words consisting of 2 or more uppercase chars that will work in SublimeText3 is...` This was excellent and worked in ST4 also. THANK you.